# Failing to connect to mongodb (mongolab) from nodejs app running localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am trying to connect using the following code.
I am running the nodejs app locally and I cannot connect to the MongoLab DB using the MongoDb Native Driver.
After about 30sec the **error** returned says:
**{"name":"MongoError","message":"no valid seed servers in list"}**

Should I declare something else somewhere? What am I missing?
When I run it live on Heroku it connects just fine.
Also, when I run it from the terminal (shell) it connects just fine.

```
   var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
   var util = require('util');
   var assert = require('assert');

   var auth = {
     user: 'root',
     pass: 'blabla',
     host: 'blabla.mongolab.com',
     port: 63879,
     name: 'heroku_blabla'
   };

        // Connection URL
        var url = util.format('mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%d/%s',
            auth.user, auth.pass, auth.host, auth.port, auth.name);

        // Use connect method to connect to the Server
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log("Connected correctly to server");

            db.close();
        });
```

Comment: Have you turned on authentication on the mongodb server?

Comment: The mongoDb server is on MongoLab. I just solved it. Check out my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it, but I don't know what caused the problem.
I suspected that it was a DNS problem.

So I went to the terminal and first run:

```
ping  ds00000.mongolab.com
```

(change 00000 to the port of your MongoLab DB)

to check the host.

Then I run: `nc -w 3 -v ds000000.mongolab.com 000000`

Finally, if those two succeed then it is not a problem with the port.

So, then I **changed the host name in my code with the IP** of that host name in mongoLab, and that solved the error that appeared. 
Note: The IP of the mongoLab DB host appears in the response of second command in your terminal.

Comment: Hey, I'm getting this error still sometimes. The 2nd command does not generate any response for me. Any idea why?